# using print format to evenly space an integer-display of one or more digits

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will display all even numbers from 2 to 20.
I am trying to display the numbers evenly by using *System.out.format* but once the numbers to be displayed increase in digits, the spacing becomes uneven.

the desired output is:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

but the output I am getting is:

```
2 4 6 8101214161820
```

here is my source code:

```
public class HelloWorld {
     public static void main(String []args) {
         final int UPPERLIMIT = 20;
         int i = 2;
         do {
             if((i % 2) == 0)
                 System.out.format("%2d",i);
             i++;
         } while(i<=UPPERLIMIT);
         System.out.println();
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried String.Format(...)?

Answer (score 3):

if the result >=10 ，it will take two space.so it will not have a space between them.
you can remove the "2" and add a space after "%d":

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     final int UPPERLIMIT =20;
             int i=2;
             do
             {

                 if((i%2)==0)
                 System.out.format("%d ",i);
                 i++;
             }
             while(i<=UPPERLIMIT);
             System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: didn't know about being able to add a space after it, much cleaner than my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot !! That really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the output is greater than 10 and if so add a third space in

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         final int UPPERLIMIT =20;
         int i=2;
         do
         {
             if(i%2 == 0){
                 if(i < 10){
                     System.out.format("%2d",i);                      
                 }
                 else{
                      System.out.format("%3d",i);                        
                 }                 
             }
             i++;
         }
         while(i<=UPPERLIMIT);
         System.out.println();   
     }
}
```